# How to check if a user exists in a GNU/Linux OS using Python?

Tags: python, unix

What is the easiest way to check the existence of a user on a GNU/Linux OS, using Python?

Anything better than issuing `ls ~login-name` and checking the exit code?

And if running under Windows?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This answer builds upon the [answer by Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2540487/832230). It adds the necessary `try...except` block.

Check if a user exists:

```
import pwd

try:
    pwd.getpwnam('someusr')
except KeyError:
    print('User someusr does not exist.')
```

Check if a group exists:

```
import grp

try:
    grp.getgrnam('somegrp')
except KeyError:
    print('Group somegrp does not exist.')
```

Answer (score 10):

To look up my userid (`bagnew`) under Unix:

```
import pwd
pw = pwd.getpwnam("bagnew")
uid = pw.pw_uid
```

See the [pwd](http://docs.python.org/library/pwd.html) module info for more.

Comment: It will raise `KeyError` if the username is not found.

Comment: I have now added an answer with the necessary `try...except` block.

Answer (score 5):

Using pwd you can get a listing of all available user entries using pwd.getpwall(). This can work if you do not like try:/except: blocks.

```
import pwd

username = "zomobiba"
usernames = [x[0] for x in pwd.getpwall()]
if username in usernames:
    print("Yay")
```

Comment: Okay, but there is no reason not to like `try...except` blocks. It is also more efficient to query a single user with `getpwnam` than to query all users with `getpwall`.

Answer (score 0):

I would parse /etc/passwd for the username in question.  Users may not necessarily have homedir's.

Comment: This will fail if e.g. LDAP is being used.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that users may not necessarily have homedirs.

Comment: I was under the impression that not all linux flavours store user info in the /etc/passwd file...

Comment: @Powertieke: They do, if the `passwd` or `shadow` NSS databases are using `files`. See the `nsswitch.conf(5)` man page for more details.

Comment: The `getent`command will check all sources. `getent passwd username`

Answer (score -1):

Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2541379/), I would do this:

```
>>> import pwd
>>> 'tshepang' in [entry.pw_name for entry in pwd.getpwall()]
True
```

Comment: I like this for its simplicity, and was about to upvote it, but unfortunately it doesn't capture all of the usernames on the system.  The `pwd.getpwnam()` API seems to work more reliably.