# start python program in the background that can prompt the user for password

Tags: python, daemon, background-process

Basically I wanted to start a daemon in the background that will still prompt the user in the console for a password.  I created this with pexpect, but when this program ends it kills the daemon since it is a child process.  So obviously pexpect isn't going to work for this.  Does any body know of a way to do this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pexpect
import getpass
child = pexpect.spawn('python daemon.py &')
child.expect_exact('Password:')

passwd = getpass.getpass()

child.sendline(passwd)

index = child.expect_exact('Started Successfully')
print index
```

Comment: Im pretty sure you cant force your prograa not to close ... and so the user can just close your program to circumvent ...

Comment: well I'm not worried if a user explicitly closes the daemon. What I am trying to do is start a background process where a user can enter a one time passphrase at the start of the daemon.

Comment: Had you considered using os.fork() and then run the daemon module?

Comment: yea, but I didn't know how to pass the password to the daemon.  Have to keep the password safe i.e. not storing on the hdd and not showing it on the screen.

Comment: I could help you if it was windows ... :/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540460/how-can-i-tell-if-a-given-login-exists-in-my-linux-box-using-python  this may be of help ...

Comment: daemon process doesn't have controlling terminal and STDIN is bind to /dev/null, and you can not feed it passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dany suggested, "Had you considered using os.fork() and then run the daemon module?"

Your answer was "yea, but I didn't know how to pass the password to the daemon. Have to keep the password safe i.e. not storing on the hdd and not showing it on the screen."

But you don't have to do anything to pass the password to the daemon. After fork, it's still accessible. For example:

```
passwd = getpass.getpass()
pid = os.fork()
if pid:
  print 'Parent thinks passwd is', passwd
else:
  print 'Child thinks passwd is', passwd
```

So, read the password in the parent, then fork the daemon; it already has the password, so it doesn't need a tty for anything. Problem solved.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to do. don't know why it didn't hit me before.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

pexpect has a method [close(self, force=True)](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html#spawn-close) which closes its connection to the child process.

According to the documentation, the child pocess is terminated if force=True so

```
child.close(force=False)
```

should disconnect, but leave the application running.

Comment: That only stops it from sending SIGKILL.  It still sends SIGHUP and SIGINT